# Сменить имя процесса PHP. cli_set_process_title. Cron

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

VDS Ubuntu 16.04
в php-скрипте:

```
<?php
cli_set_process_title ("MY_PROCESS_NAME");
...
```

Отслеживаю запущенные процессы через htop в Ubuntu.
Если запустить php-скрипт вручную из консоли, то назначенные имя процесса отображается.
Если же php-скрипт запускается по Cron, то не отображается. 
Почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Это связано с тем, что когда вы запускаете скрипт вручную, он выполняется в контексте вашей консоли, и любое назначение имени процесса, сделанное через cli_set_process_title, будет отображаться в списке процессов, запущенных из этой консоли, т.е. видно здесь и сейчас только в Вашем терминале. Если Вы запустите ещё один терминал - уже не будет отображаться.

Когда скрипт запускается по крону, он выполняется в другом контексте, не связанным с консолью, где Вы запускали вручную. И получается что любое назначение имени процесса, сделанное в скрипте через cli_set_process_title, не будет видно в списке процессов, которые были созданы в Вашей консоли.